# how to apply "or" operation to tensor with float32 type?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to merge two sparse Bird-Eye-View feature maps.

They have value 0 on most pixels. And They are aligned so the corresponding pixels represents the same location, which makes the merging reasonable.

- Given two tensors as example:

```
net1=[
[0,   0.2, 0], 
[0,   0.1, 0],
[0,   0  , 0]]

net2_aligned=[
[0.3, 0  , 0], 
[0,   0.4, 0],
[0,   0  , 0]]
```

- only if the net1's pixel has value 0, will it be replaced by the corresponding pixel's value from net2_aligned.

  - (Also acceptable if you use max/mean for the pixels having value in both tensors)
- I.e. we suppose to get this result after the "OR-operation" for float32:

```
net_result=[
[0.3, 0.2, 0], 
[0  , 0.1, 0],
[0  , 0  , 0]]
```

Is there such a method in tensorflow? I am thinking if it could be done with a special 1x1 Convolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
import tensorflow as tf

net1 = tf.convert_to_tensor([[0,   0.2, 0], 
                             [0,   0.1, 0],
                             [0,   0  , 0]])
net2_aligned = tf.convert_to_tensor([[0.3, 0  , 0], 
                                     [0,   0.4, 0],
                                     [0,   0  , 0]])

bools = (net1==0) # Gives a boolean tensor
bools = tf.cast(bools, tf.float32) # Converts the boolean tensor to float32 dtype, so you can multiply it with net2_aligned 

net_result = net1 + bools*net2_aligned # This is possible thanks to the particularity of your problem, as each time you want to replace a net1 value by one of net2_aligned, it is equal to 0. Thus the sum.
```

Output :

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.3, 0.2, 0. ],
       [0. , 0.1, 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. ]], dtype=float32)>
```

---

If you wanted to replace each value of `net1` that is equal to, let's say, `0.2`, you could have done :

```
bools = tf.cast(net1==0.2, tf.float32)
net_result = net1*(1-bools) + bools*net2_aligned
```

Comment: when it comes into 4-D tensor, the bools doesn't works well. `ValueError: Shapes () and (?, 63, 126, 80) are incompatible`. Do you know a way to improve `bools = (net1==0)` in the 4-D case?

Comment: Are you sure about that? It works perfectly for me, you can try for example with the tensor `[[[[1,0],[0,2]],[[4,5],[5,0]]],[[[0,0],[1,1]],[[8,0],[0,0]]]]` (quite ugly I know). Don't you think the problem rather comes from your tensor ? Since your first dimension doesn't seem to be defined (as there's a `?`).

Comment: I train with batch size=4, the first dimension is thus unknown. I inspected the value at the corner pixel: it is a float, equal to 0 in half of the probes. So the focus is on the line `bools = (net1==0)` with unknown dimension of `net1`

Answer (score 1):

You could use numpy for this:

```
import numpy as np

net1=np.array([
[0,   0.2, 0], 
[0,   0.1, 0],
[0,   0  , 0]])

net2_aligned=np.array([
[0.3, 0  , 0], 
[0,   0.4, 0],
[0,   0  , 0]])

result = np.copy(net1)
mask = net1 == 0

result[mask] = net2_aligned[mask]
print(result)
```